# Pelican I18N Sub-sites Plugin without hardcoded PLUGIN_PATHS

Tags: pelican

I am using Pelican to develop a full multilingual site.

Everything is fully working thanks to the great plugin I18N Sub-sites: https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/i18n_subsites

To make that plugin work, I added the full path of my pelican plugins to the main configuration:

```
PLUGIN_PATHS = ['/path/to/pelican-plugins']
```

I want to share the site with a small tean, so everyone can work on it.
So, I would like to remove that hardcoded path from my settings.

The plugin is not "pip-installable".

I would like that my team would not need to download the pelican-plugins repository and manually change that path.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative paths in `PLUGIN_PATHS`. They will be relative to the settings file. So you can do a folder structure like this:

```
_ site
  |_ pelicanconf.py
  |_ content
     |_ ...
  |_ plugins
     |_ i18n_subsites
     |_ ...
```

And use

```
PLUGIN_PATHS = ['plugins']
```

Then, you can just share the `site` folder with your team.